# Self-inductance of a given Setup

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electromagnetic-induction, inductance

[image]

I am asked to prove that the self inductance of the system is given by

[image]

I used Ampere's Law to find the magnetic field between the strips:

[image]

The magnetic field due to the second strip would be the same which would yield a value of |B| =

[image]

What bugs me is the last step to calculate the inductance, for which I have used two methods(with different answers):

[image]

[image]

Something tells me that the first method is incorrect and I need some conceptual clarity. I am not able to figure out my mistake. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just messed up the dimensions a bit and forgot to consider the magnetic field due to the bottom sheet as well. The area through which the magnetic field is passing through is $al$, not $bl$.

So, it's $2((muknot)(I)/2b)*al=LI$ which gives us the correct answer.